Getting max value of an Image efficiently
I have some satellite TIFF assets in my Earth Engine project. Each of the images has a single band and I would like to extract the max value of an image. The images are big worldwide high resolution satellite images, so an approach using the reduceRegion takes some long time.
The objective is to be able to have a function that returns the country where the max value of the image occurs, so specifying the bestEffort: true might not work in some cases.
Any method that I'm not finding or any workaround?
Just in case, I'm loading the image from the Python API like
image = ee.Image("path/to/image/asset")


Parallelize over multiple regions, using reduceRegions on, say, the LSIB country borders.
max = image.reduceRegions({
    collection: ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017"),
    reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
}.sort("max", false).first()

Set the scale to whatever threshold of approximation you're willing to accept.  Also, maybe filter out Antarctica, it's big and you probably don't care about it.
